# Version conflict with Castle.Core when using White and NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, selenium, castle

I found an issue trying to add White functionality to our testing framework based on Selenium WebDriver. After adding all references to project, it compiles
without errors. But it throws an exception when using method 
Application.GetWindow(windowTitle):

```
Application application = Application.Attach(processID);
Window downloadWindow = application.GetWindow(windowTitle);
```

ex.Message="Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies.
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I downloaded latest version of Castle.Core but problem remains. So I remove references to the last version of Castle.Core and add references with NuGet to Castle.DynamicProxy
and Castle.Core 1.2.0 (this version I used for separate tests and they work). But with obsolete versions of Castle.Core there is an issue with NHibernate. It does not work.

Is there any decisions for such problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add an assembly binding in your web.config (or app.config) to forward the current version to return when resolving 1.2.0.0:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.0.0" newVersion="2.5.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

And hope that they are compatible. I'm not sure that the publicKeyToken is the same, that is the one from 1.2.0.0 so you should change that to reflect 2.5.2.0 I think, or if it wants the 1.2.0.0 token.

Comment: I create app.config with such assembly binding but unfortunately it also does not work. Now the message is "Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=2.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Comment: Well, what version of Castle.Core are you using in your app then?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Now I use 1.2.0.0 in project. NHibernate begins to work. But Castle.Core is still does not work